# How can I have the car body contain multiple objects with "Offroad Rig Generator Setup for Geometrynodes"

Tags: rigging, objects, geometry-nodes, parent, path

I have downloaded "Offroad Rig Generator Setup for Geometrynodes": [Download it here.](https://blenderesse.gumroad.com/l/momhq)

I want to have multible objects attached to the car body as shown on the car on the right.
[image: What I want to make]

The node setup does only allow one object as the car body:

[image: Only one object.]

Is there a way I can have the car body being a collection instead of just one object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

1. In the node setup zoom in on this Object Info node:

[image: Node setup]

[image: Objcet Info node]

2. Replace it with a collection info node.
   [image: Collection Info node]
3. Press "n" on the keybord then click on "Group" and select the "Body" input.
4. Change the "Type" from "Object" to "Collection".

[image: Change the "Type" from "Object" to "Collection"]

Now the body can be a collection instead of just a single object.

[image: Now it works]